# How to map the Byte in Springs form:select?

Tags: java, spring

In my **model** I have the variables
Byte low = 0;
Byte high = 1;

Now low and high can map to 3 values those are in String O1 , O2 , O3 ;

for example if low = 0 it can map to O1 , if 1 it will map to O2.
This is same for high also.

How should I design my controller to manipulate these values through JSP page.

I have the enum for O1,O2,O3

like

```
enum MyEnum {
 O1(0),O2(1),O3(2) so on...
}
```

I want the dropdown using form:options which will show these three enum options for low as well as for high.

The only question here is I have read [How do I set the selected value in a Spring MVC form:select from the controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181277/how-do-i-set-the-selected-value-in-a-spring-mvc-formselect-from-the-controller) but I am not able to figure out how my Byte values will create the map. I want to populate these values.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think that you should use the enum in your model instead of byte. You can always get the byte value from the enum. Also add methods to the model class to return either the byte value or the string value of the enum. Then use this string value for your select input box.

Your enum(my assumption):

```
public enum MyEnum {
    O1 (0),
    O2 (1),
    O3 (2);

    private final Byte byteVal;       

    private MyEnum(Byte val) {
        byteVal = val;
    }

    public Byte getByteVal(){
        return byteVal;
    }

}
```

Your model(my assumption):

```
public class MyModel{
    MyEnum high; //instead of Byte high
    MyEnum low;//instead of Bye low
    ....
    //This method would return byte to be compatible with your backend as it is right now
    public Byte getHigh(){
        return this.high.getByteVal();
    }
    //This method would allow you to use the string representation for your front end
    public Byte getHighString(){
        return this.high.name();
    }
}
```

Now use model.highString instead of model.high in your jsp for your select box.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here high and low are Byte , and depending upon there values they will either point to O1 or O2 and so on..

Comment: High and low are just just bytes. You happen to correlate them with an enum. But a better utilization of the enum would be to use the enum values directly as high and low.

Comment: If you really, really want you can always keep everything else the same, modify your enum to allow you to get enum bye the byte value(static method accessing a private map perhaps) and add get highString method in your model as the follows(this would allow you to keep your current model as is with byte members):
    public Byte getHighString(){
        return MyEnum.getByByte(high);
    }