# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[]

Tags: spring, jsp

When I try to add a selector and then pick an option, the script errors.

```
<form:select propertyContainer="${searchCriteria}" id="macroconditions" liveSearch="true" name="macroconditions" propertyPath="macroconditions" convertsToAccordion="true"/>
```

The log shows:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[value=text of the selector]
```

SearchCriteria Script:

```
private EclMacroconditionCollection macroconditions;

    public EclMacroconditionCollection getMacroconditions() {
    if (macroconditions == null){
        macroconditions = new EclMacroconditionCollection(EclMacrocondition.class);
        Object period = getValueFromCookie(getPeriod());
        macroconditions.getMacroconditions(period == null ? null : period.toString());
    }
    return macroconditions;
}

public void setMacroconditions(EclMacroconditionCollection macroconditions) {
    this.macroconditions = macroconditions;
}
```

thanks

Comment: what is `listString`? share more code.

Comment: is the list text that show in the pick selector

Comment: `path` property is not set for `form:select`. Look at this [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181277/how-do-i-set-the-selected-value-in-a-spring-mvc-formselect-from-the-controller)

Comment: is set with propertyPath="macroconditions"